# How to use joomla.asset.json correctly?

Tags: joomla-4, json

I figured I need to reinstall a template/extension in order to take into account my changes to the `joomla.asset.json` file. Here is the file I'm currently using:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "my-template",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "template description",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "template.offline",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "offline.css"
    },
    {
      "name": "template.style",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "template.css"
    },
    {
      "name": "template.script",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "template.js"
    },
    {
      "name": "template.preset",
      "type": "preset",
      "dependencies": [
        "template.style#style",
        "template.script#script"
      ]      
    }
  ]
}
```

However there are a few things I don't quite understand:

- how can I make Joomla acknowledge my `joomla.asset.json` changes without reinstalling extensions?
- why the web asset manager loads `finder.min.js` when my template doesn't ask for it? is it requested for the `mod_search`? further more I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: a is not a constructor at finder.min.js:1` when again my template doesn't ask for it;
- then there is the issue in `core.js` dependency of the original `cassiopeia/joomla.asset.json` for various scripts, does it mean my own `joomla.asset.json` defined scripts have to have the `core.js` as dependency as well? As you can see in the image below, the `joomla-alert.min.css` as well as many other assets are loaded without asking for it, I believe that is outside the template own asset manager control.
  [image: joomla-asset-screenshot]
- are the above related in any way?

I will update the above with further findings.

Testing with latest Joomla 4.0.0 beta.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### To your first question "how can I make Joomla acknowledge my joomla.asset.json changes without reinstalling extensions?"

1. I think it is not right that you have to reinstall the extension after every change in the file `joomla.asset.json`. It is only necessary the first time you add the `joomla.asset.json` file. So that Joomla registers this file. So you need one install with the entry

```
    <media folder="media/com_foos" destination="com_foos">
        <folder>js</folder>
        <filename>joomla.asset.json</filename>
    </media>
```

in the install manifest. If you create the file `joomla.asset.json` and do not install, Joomla does not know the file - with some other files this is possible. But, if Joomla knows `joomla.asset.json`, you can edit the content later.

I had the following file and renamed the javascript from `foos-modal.js` to `admin-foos-modal.js`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "com_foos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Joomla CMS",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "com_foos.admin-foos-modal",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_foos/foos-modal.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "defer": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I didn't have to reinstall my extension while developing. I only changed the `uri`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "com_foos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Joomla CMS",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "com_foos.admin-foos-modal",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_foos/admin-foos-modal.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "defer": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The renamed file was recognised. It is also possible to change the attributes, for example change `defer` to `false`.

2. Secondly, you don't have to use the `joomla.asset.json` file. In the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Web_Assets) you will find many entries like: `Register custom item without json definition`. For example, for a StyleSheet.

```
...
// Register custom item without json definition
$wa->registerStyle('bar', 'com_example/bar.css', [], ['data-foo' => 'some attribute'], ['some.dependency']);
// And use it later
$wa->useStyle('bar');
...
```

### To your second question: "why the web asset manager loads finder.min.js when my template doesn't ask for it? is it requested for the mod_search? further more I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: a is not a constructor at finder.min.js:1 when again my template doesn't ask for it;"

We needed your code to answer this question. It may be that you insert a dependency that has the file `finder.min.js` as a dependency.
Or you have the Finder search active in your website and the file is loaded because of the Finder [joomla.asset.json](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/build/media_source/com_finder/joomla.asset.json)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "com_finder",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "Joomla CMS",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "com_finder.dates",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "com_finder/dates.min.css"
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.filters.es5",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/filters-es5.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "nomodule": true,
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.filters",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/filters.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "com_finder.filters.es5"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.finder",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "com_finder/finder.min.css"
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.finder.es5",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/finder-es5.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "nomodule": true,
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.finder",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/finder.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "com_finder.finder.es5"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.finder-edit.es5",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/finder-edit-es5.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "nomodule": true,
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.finder-edit",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/finder-edit.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "com_finder.finder-edit.es5"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.index.es5",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/index-es5.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "nomodule": true,
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.index",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/index.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "com_finder.index.es5"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.indexer",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "com_finder/indexer.min.css"
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.indexer.es5",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/indexer-es5.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "nomodule": true,
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.indexer",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/indexer.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "com_finder.indexer.es5"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.maps.es5",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/maps-es5.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "nomodule": true,
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_finder.maps",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_finder/maps.min.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "com_finder.maps.es5"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### EDIT

I think it is important to understand that the [Joomla Web Assets Manager](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Web_Assets) manages all assets in a Joomla installation. If I see it correctly, it does not apply specifically to a template. If an extension is loaded and needs these assets, it can also use the Web Assets Manager. But: It does not have to. Assets can still be included via `Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper` - for example via `HTMLHelper::_('jquery.framework');.` **The advantage of the Webassets Manager** is that it ensures that these assets are no longer loaded twice if two extension include the same file. And the Assets are loaded in the correct order. This prevents conflicts.

I can't see in your image that a `finder.min.js` file is included in the `head`. By the way : `com_finder` has nothing to do with `mod_search`. [com_search](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/search) was [decoupled](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/20637) in Joomla 4. Maybe you can still find it in your installation for backwards compatibility reasons. Nevertheless:
Finder is now the default search and the assets are called `finder*`. The assets of `*_search` are called `search*`. The error `Uncaught TypeError: a is not a constructor at finder.min.js:1` probably occurred when you included a Finder extension and the file `finder.min.js` was loaded because of the [joomla.asset.json](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/build/media_source/com_finder/joomla.asset.json).

I can't answer the other questions. I've been reading up on web assets mainly for embedding in a component. But I can imagine that you need the file `core.js` for editing in the frontend. You will certainly need `searchtools.js` for list views where you want to offer functions for searching, filtering and sorting via Joomla. But these are only assumptions. If I had to implement now, I would look at the file and decide on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question with some clarification.

Comment: Please see if my addition to the answer helps you.