# Load CSS so as to be able to be overriden Joomla 4

Tags: css

Some years ago, the question of how to load CSS in a way that permits a template override was answered [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13939/how-to-override-an-extension-css-file) with:

```
 JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'mod_module/style.css', ['relative' => true]);
```

Recently, I found it seemed not to work with Joomla 3.10.11 but the following did:

```
 use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
 ... 
 HTMLHelper::_('stylesheet', 'component/com_component/component.css', ['relative' => true], false);
```

However, it did not work in Joomla 4, no CSS was loaded. What is the code to use for Joomla 4? Is there code that will work in both 3.10.x and Joomla 4.x?

Comment: Could you update your question with the path of your extension CSS file and the template override path?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know the template override path. The problem I have is that the CSS doesn’t get loaded at all. The path to CSS was your example, but I am working with a component so have amended my example.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 4 implements the concept of Web Assets Manager, with which you need to include and use various assets - js and css.

- [Official docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Web_Assets)
- [There is an article about it](https://jpath.ru/docs/output/js-css/kak-pravilno-podklyuchat-javascript-i-css-v-joomla-4) (in Russian)
- [Answer on SO](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/29044/how-to-use-joomla-asset-json-correctly)